# Content Server Request Failed

Tags: oracle-jet

This error took me a long time and I couldn't find a solution for it.

The problem is when I go to https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/cookbook I see the error:

> Content Server Request Failed
> Unable to download '(null)'. 'path:/Enterprise Libraries/webfolder/technetwork/jet/cookbook' is not a document.

Comment: Were you maybe looking for https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html ?

Comment: yes your URL give the cookbook tree but the above is very helpfull